# Windows universal app 8.1 in windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, compatibility

I start to developing windows universal application for windows 8.1 and windows phone. I start in windows 8.1(visual studio 2013) After some time I was install window 10 on my computer , i set again vs2013 and now app is work, but when I make package(store/create app package) and install on tablet with windows 8.1 application is minimize itself on start. When i maximize again app minimize itself... 
I try with same code to make package on computer with windows 8.1 and this time app work perfectly.

It is possible to make package for windows store app that work in windows 8.1 as store app, when visual studio is install on windows 10.

I am not sure is this clear question, and i don't understand what is problem with app when in visual studio work as charm, what is difference, maybe is something with compiler.

Please Help,
Thank you

Comment: I've seen a lot of Store apps that did this.  "Minimize" was not the correct word for them, "crash" is.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank for answer , i really not know what happen. I assume that you are right, but do you maybe know what can be reason when only different thing are OS in witch i working, i assume that is some compatibility thing? Thank you

Comment: Universal apps for 8.1 use other SDK that Universal apps for windows 10, so you need to install both SDK and then select that you want to create a project for 8.1

Comment: @ganchito55 Thank you very much , but i already have windows 8.1 sdk...

Comment: Did you mean your app can run in windows 8.1,but cannot run in windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably selecting Windows 10 `Universal` template. You should probably select the `Windows 8-> Universal template`.
[image: Screenshot of template]